# UK Citizen visiting Norway for a month volunteering

Tags: visas, uk-citizens, norway, volunteering

My son, a 26 year old English university student and bird watching fanatic is hoping to go to Norway for one month to a nature reserve to assist in bird ringing, migration monitoring and other related activities. These are all things that he does here in England. He will be paying for travel to and from Norway and will be given accommodation and food. There is no monetary remuneration.

I know that he can go to Norway for up to 90 days without a visa but wonder if the activities he will be undertaking will be classified as requiring a residence permit.

I've tried asking VFS Global (mentioned on the Norwegian Embassy website as being the point of contact for visa related questions) without any success.

Can anyone offer any advice?

Comment: What did the nature reserve in Norway say when he asked them about visa requirements?

Comment: Schengen visas usually allow unpaid volunteering for short stays, and residence permits are only required for paid work or stays over 3 months.

Comment: Isn't board and lodging classed as remuneration? [Norway in United Kingdom](https://www.norway.no/en/uk/services-info/visitors-visa-res-permit/) states that a Visitor's Visa is for "Holidays, visits to family and friends, business", and a Residence Permit is for "Work, studies, au pair, family immigration". Wouldn't you be similar to an au pair, who is typically working in exchange for board and lodging? Or perhaps you need a Schengen Visa.

Comment: @Traveller they would not offer advise

Comment: In general nobody will commit on questions like this, leaving the traveler to hope for the best at passport control.  It's far from ideal.  Is there any way to find out from the nature reserve whether they have hosted other non-EU, non-EEA volunteers and whether they have had any trouble with the authorities?

Comment: @phoog In all likelihood, absolutely no one will care. No one is going to question a UK citizen upon entering Norway about the purpose of their stay. If the OP wants be super safe, he can contact the Norwegian Directorate of Immigration: https://www.udi.no/en/contact-us/